# How do I replace the list of nan with list of zeroes in a pandas dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe. How do I replace the list of nan with list of zeroes?

```
a   b            
1   [nan, nan]
5   [nan, nan, nan]
0   [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `explode` + `fillna` + `groupby`:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].explode().fillna(0).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Another option is list comprehension:

```
df['b'] = [[0 if isinstance(x, float) and np.isnan(x) else x for x in lst] for lst in df['b']]
```

Output:

```
   a          b
0  1     [0, 0]
1  5  [0, 0, 0]
2  0     [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a list comprehension?

```
df['b'] = [[0 if pd.isna(y) else y for y in x] for x in df['b']]
df
 
   a          b
0  1     [0, 0]
1  5  [0, 0, 0]
2  0     [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `fillna` by temporarily converting to Series:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).fillna(0).to_list())
```

*NB. This is probably not efficient on large datasets. The list comprehension is very likely the fastest.*